Jetpack Compose Tooltip in DropdownMenu not following anchor
I'm writing a button that similar to the FAB that locates at the bottom right, it's supposed to work like:
Click the Button -> Popup a DropdownMenu with an "info" icon -> Click the icon to show a Tooltip beside it.

But the tooltip is not aligned to the "info" icon, why is that?
The code:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            Scaffold {
                // Full fill the entire screen
                Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

                    // This Box is for aligning the content at the bottom end,
                    //  and DropdownMenu requires a Box container.
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                    ) {
                        var dropdownExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

                        Button(
                            onClick = { dropdownExpanded = !dropdownExpanded },
                        ) {
                            Text("dropdown")
                        }

                        DropdownMenu(
                            expanded = dropdownExpanded,
                            onDismissRequest = {},
                        ) {
                            TooltipImage() // the only menu item
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TooltipImage() {
    val tooltipState = rememberTooltipState(isPersistent = true)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    TooltipBox(
        positionProvider = TooltipDefaults.rememberRichTooltipPositionProvider(),
        tooltip = {
            RichTooltip { Text("tooltip content") }
        },
        state = tooltipState
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details),
            contentDescription = "",
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    scope.launch { tooltipState.show() }
                }
        )
    }
}

Edited:
The answer is correct, however, when I add a TextField on that Dropdown and when it's focused, the input caret is also mis-aligned at the top. The TextField doesn't seem to support the position provicer, I ended up using popup dialog instead of dropdown menu.

The reason this happens is when you open a DropDownMenu which is a PopUp you create a new window with anchor positioned in (0,22) on my emulator, you can check how a DropDown and Tooltip is positioned in this answer.
And if you debug TooltipDefaults.rememberRichTooltipPositionProvider() you can see anchorBounds are not where they supposed to be on screen.
What you can do get position of DropDownMenu on screen with
Modifier
    .onGloballyPositioned {
        offset = it.positionOnScreen()
    }

write your own PopupPositionProvider with this offset for TooltipBox as
@Composable
fun rememberPositionProvider(
    spacingBetweenTooltipAndAnchor: Dp = SpacingBetweenTooltipAndAnchor,
    userOffset: IntOffset = IntOffset.Zero
): PopupPositionProvider {
    val tooltipAnchorSpacing = with(LocalDensity.current) {
        spacingBetweenTooltipAndAnchor.roundToPx()
    }
    return remember(tooltipAnchorSpacing, userOffset) {
        object : PopupPositionProvider {
            override fun calculatePosition(
                anchorBounds: IntRect,
                windowSize: IntSize,
                layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
                popupContentSize: IntSize
            ): IntOffset {

                val newBounds = anchorBounds.translate(userOffset)

                var x = newBounds.right
                // Try to shift it to the left of the anchor
                // if the tooltip would collide with the right side of the screen
                if (x + popupContentSize.width > windowSize.width) {
                    x = newBounds.left - popupContentSize.width
                    // Center if it'll also collide with the left side of the screen
                    if (x < 0)
                        x = newBounds.left +
                                (newBounds.width - popupContentSize.width) / 2
                }

               //  This is a line i added you might check for right side
               // overflowing as well
                x += popupContentSize.width / 2 + anchorBounds.width / 2

                // Tooltip prefers to be above the anchor,
                // but if this causes the tooltip to overlap with the anchor
                // then we place it below the anchor
                var y = newBounds.top - popupContentSize.height - tooltipAnchorSpacing
                if (y < 0)
                    y = newBounds.bottom + tooltipAnchorSpacing
                return IntOffset(x, y)
            }
        }
    }
}

internal val SpacingBetweenTooltipAndAnchor = 4.dp

And apply it as
@Preview
@Composable
fun TooltipTest() {
    Scaffold {
        // Full fill the entire screen
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

            // This Box is for aligning the content at the bottom end,
            //  and DropdownMenu requires a Box container.
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
            ) {
                var dropdownExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

                Button(
                    onClick = { dropdownExpanded = !dropdownExpanded },
                ) {
                    Text("dropdown")
                }

                var offset by remember {
                    mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero)
                }

                DropdownMenu(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .onGloballyPositioned {
                            offset = it.positionOnScreen()
                        },
                    expanded = dropdownExpanded,
                    onDismissRequest = {},
                ) {
                    TooltipImage(
                        offset = offset.round()
                    ) // the only menu item
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TooltipImage(
    offset: IntOffset
) {
    val tooltipState = rememberTooltipState(isPersistent = true)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    TooltipBox(
        positionProvider = rememberPositionProvider(userOffset = offset),
        tooltip = {
            RichTooltip { Text("tooltip content") }
        },
        state = tooltipState
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details),
            contentDescription = "",
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    scope.launch { tooltipState.show() }
                }
        )
    }
}

Result

